# Difference between "noise cancellation" and "noise reduction"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, terminology

Am I right to think that the expression "noise cancellation" is used for sound noise and "noise reduction" for image noise?

Comment: This question would be better if you explained why you think this is the case.

Answer (score 12):

*noise cancellation* and *noise reduction* have technical definitions and both can refer to *any* electronic signal, whether audio, image or otherwise.

*noise reduction* is any technique used to filter out noise, while *noise cancellation* is the active electronic process of determining the part of the signal that is noise, then adding *the opposite* noise signal back into the original signal, thereby subtracting out the original noise.

(I'm a software engineer)

Answer (score 2):

Partially: "noise reduction" can be used at times for sounds as well.

Answer (score 1):

No. Noise cancellation and noise reduction can be used for sound and image. I presume by image noise you mean a noise made by an image on something like a tv screen?